# Shorten Localhost URL

Tags: apache, localhost, port

I recently changed my Apache Server's port number from 80 to 8079. Now when I need to access my localhost, I have to type `http://localhost:8079`. How can I access my localhost again by typing only `http://localhost`?

Comment: You can't. When you don't specify a port, browsers assume port 80 for HTTP and port 443 for HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

Change it back to 80. 80 is the HTTP port, 443 is the standard HTTPS port. If you want to use something different, you're going to have to include the port.

Comment: I'll have to stick with 8079 as port 80 will be used by FileMaker Server I just installed, or perhaps I'll try to change the FileMaker Server's port number instead.